# How to generate auto-incrementing ID in R

Tags: r

I am looking for an efficient way to create unique, numeric IDs for some synthetic data I'm generating.

Right now, I simply have a function that emits and increments a value from a global variable (see demo code below). However, this is messy because I must init the `idCounter` variable and I'd rather not use global variables if possible.

```
# Emit SSN
idCounter = 0
emitID = function(){
  # Turn into a formatted string
  id = formatC(idCounter,width=9,flag=0,format="d")

  # Increment id counter
  idCounter <<- idCounter+1

  return(id)
}
record$id = emitID()
```

The `uuid` package provides functionality close to what I want, but I need IDs to be integers only. Any suggestions? Perhaps a way to convert the UUID value into a numeric value of some sort? Obviously some collisions would occur but that'd probably be ok. I think, at most, I'd need 1 billion values.

Thanks for any suggestions!

-Rob

Comment: contradictory requirements: "unique", "Obviously some collisions would occur but that'd probably be ok"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A non-global version of the counter uses lexical scope to encapsulate `idCounter` with the increment function

```
emitID <- local({
    idCounter <- -1L
    function(){
        idCounter <<- idCounter + 1L                     # increment
        formatC(idCounter, width=9, flag=0, format="d")  # format & return
    }
})
```

and then

```
> emitID()
[1] "000000000"
> emitID1()
[1] "000000001"
> idCounter <- 123   ## global variable, not locally scoped idCounter
> emitID()
[1] "000000002"
```

A fun alternative is to use a 'factory' pattern to create independent counters. Your question implies that you'll call this function a billion (hmm, not sure where I got that impression...) times, so maybe it makes sense to vectorize the call to formatC by creating a buffer of ids?

```
idFactory <- function(buf_n=1000000) {
    curr <- 0L
    last <- -1L
    val <- NULL
    function() {
        if ((curr %% buf_n) == 0L) {
            val <<- formatC(last + seq_len(buf_n), width=9, flag=0, format="d")
            last <<- last + buf_n
            curr <<- 0L
        }
        val[curr <<- curr + 1L]
    }
}
emitID2 <- idFactory()
```

and then (`emitID1` is an instance of the local variable version above).

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(emitID1(), emitID2(), times=100000)
Unit: microseconds
      expr    min     lq median     uq      max neval
 emitID1() 66.363 70.614 72.310 73.603 13753.96 1e+05
 emitID2()  2.240  2.982  4.138  4.676 49593.03 1e+05
> emitID1()
[1] "000100000"
> emitID2()
[1] "000100000"
```

(the proto solution is about 3x slower than `emitID1`, though speed is not everything).

Comment: +1 for `local`. Don't think I've ever seen anyone actually use it before.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen I'll agree I haven't seen it for this purpose but I have used local in startup scripts.

Comment: I've never seen the locally scoping before - very cool! It does exactly what I was trying to do. Also, the factory option is great, as I'll want to generate several independent sets of IDs. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Wanted to see how this compared to using options to store the value, e.g. emitID3 <- function(){
 idCounter <- getOption("MyUniqueUUID")
 idCounter <- ifelse(is.null(idCounter),0L,idCounter)
 options(MyUniqueUUID=idCounter+1L)
 return(formatC(idCounter, width=9, flag=0, format="d"))
} Turns out it's about 40% slower than emitID1

Answer (score 5):

I like to use the `proto` package for small OO programming. Under the hood, it uses environments in a similar fashion to what Martin Morgan illustrated.

```
# this defines your class
library(proto)
Counter <- proto(idCounter = 0L)
Counter$emitID <- function(self = .) {
   id <- formatC(self$idCounter, width = 9, flag = 0, format = "d")
   self$idCounter <- self$idCounter + 1L
   return(id)
}

# This creates an instance (or you can use `Counter` directly as a singleton)
mycounter <- Counter$proto()

# use it:
mycounter$emitID()
# [1] "000000000"
mycounter$emitID()
# [1] "000000001"
```