# How can I subset a dataframe according to group membership?

Tags: r, unique, subset

I am wanting to write a function so that a (potentially large) dataframe can be subsetted according to group membership, where a 'group' is a unique combination of a set of column values.
For example, I would like to subset the following data frame according to unique combination of the first two columns (Loc1 and Loc2).

```
Loc1 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B")  
Loc2 <- c("a","a","b","b","a","a","b")  
Dat1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)  
Dat2 <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,2)  
Dat3 <- c(2,2,4,4,6,5,3)  
DF=data.frame(Loc1,Loc2,Dat1,Dat2,Dat3)  

  Loc1 Loc2 Dat1 Dat2 Dat3
1    A    a    1    1    2
2    A    a    1    2    2
3    A    b    1    1    4
4    A    b    1    2    4
5    B    a    1    1    6
6    B    a    1    2    5
7    B    b    1    2    3
```

I want to return (i) the number of groups (i.e. 4), (ii) the number in each group (i.e. c(2,2,2,1), and (iii) to relabel the rows so that I can further analyse the data frame according to group membership (e.g. for ANOVA and MANOVA) (i.e.

```
Group<-as.factor(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4))
Data <- cbind(Group,DF[,-1:-2])

  Group Dat1 Dat2 Dat3
1     1    1    1    2
2     1    1    2    2
3     2    1    1    4
4     2    1    2    4
5     3    1    1    6
6     3    1    2    5
7     4    1    2    3
```

).

So far all I have managed is to get the number of groups, and I'm suspicious that there's a better way to do even this:

```
nrow(unique(DF[,1:2]))
```

I was hoping to avoid for-loops as I am concerned about the function being slow.

I have tried converting to a data matrix so that I could concatenate the row values but I couldn't get that to work either.

Many thanks

Comment: how do you want to relabel the rows?

Comment: With a grouping factor. In the example this was as.factor(c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4)). Thanks

Comment: @Anna Jackson Have you tried my method?

Comment: Yes, I am looking at your original answer now and find it the simplest (the interaction one). I'm quite slow sorry!!!

Comment: @Anna Jackson I changed `interaction` to create the order as you wanted.

Comment: All this information that you are adding in the comments should have been in the original question in the first place.  It can change the problem considerably

Comment: @Richare Scriven Sorry, I didn't realise it wasn't clear. My first sentence was meant to indicate that there could be a variable number of columns, but I guess my example took over.

Comment: @Anna Jackson I updated with a function.  Not sure if that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

Create `Group` column by using `unique` level combination of `Loc1` and `Loc2`.

```
  indx <- paste(DF[,1], DF[,2])
  DF$Group <- as.numeric(factor(indx, unique(indx))) #query No (iii)
  DF1 <- DF[-(1:2)][,c(4,1:3)]
 #  Group Dat1 Dat2 Dat3
 #1     1    1    1    2
 #2     1    1    2    2
 #3     2    1    1    4
 #4     2    1    2    4
 #5     3    1    1    6
 #6     3    1    2    5
 #7     4    1    2    3


 table(DF$Group) #(No. ii)

 #1 2 3 4 
 #2 2 2 1 

 length(unique(DF$Group)) #(i)
 #[1] 4
```

Then, if you need to subset the datasets by group, you could split the dataset using the `Group` to create a list of `4` list elements

```
  split(DF1, DF1$Group)
```

#### Update

If you have multiple columns, you could still try:

```
   ColstoGroup <- 1:2
   indx <- apply(DF[,ColstoGroup], 1, paste, collapse="") 
   as.numeric(factor(indx, unique(indx)))
   #[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4
```

You could create a function;

```
 fun1 <- function(dat, GroupCols){
  FactGroup <- dat[, GroupCols]
  if(length(GroupCols)==1){
  dat$Group <- as.numeric(factor(FactGroup, levels=unique(FactGroup)))
  }
  else {
 indx <- apply(FactGroup, 1, paste, collapse="")
 dat$Group <- as.numeric(factor(indx, unique(indx)))
 }
 dat
 }

 fun1(DF, "Loc1")
 fun1(DF, c("Loc1", "Loc2"))
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how many columns there will be, and it will change depending on the data that is entered. In some cases there will only be one column, in others there will be many.

Comment: @Anna Jackson But you might be knowing which columns you wanted as `grouping`, right? Or it has to be determined by some other criteria.

Comment: It would be user defined in the function inputs, eg function(DF, a=1) where a >= 1 factor columns

Comment: @Anna Jackson If there is only one column, you don't need the `paste`.  It would be just `as.numeric(factor(DF[,Colnumber]))`

Answer (score 0):

This gets all three of your queries.

Begin with a `table` of the first two columns and then work with that data.

```
> (tab <- table(DF$Loc1, DF$Loc2))
#   
#    a b
#  A 2 2
#  B 2 1 
#
> (ct <- c(tab))                                       ## (ii)
# [1] 2 2 2 1
> length(unlist(dimnames(tab)))                        ## (i)
# [1] 4
> cbind(Group = rep(seq_along(ct), ct), DF[-c(1,2)])   ## (iii)
#  Group Dat1 Dat2 Dat3  
# 1     1    1    1    2
# 2     1    1    2    2
# 3     2    1    1    4
# 4     2    1    2    4
# 5     3    1    1    6
# 6     3    1    2    5
# 7     4    1    2    3
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would this work if there were more than 2 columns? Say I had regions, locations, and sites nested within each other and I wanted to label the rows according to the unique sites?

Comment: You can still get a table for more than two columns.  You could use `ftable`  For example, with your sample data look at `ftable(DF)` and `attributes(ftable(DF))`

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it now, but am quite slow sorry!

Comment: Another option would be `tapply` to apply a table over the desired columns.

Comment: Could you please give an example as to how this would work for the first 3 columns of DF, leaving just 2 columns of data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing a bit from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902257/how-to-generate-auto-incrementing-id-in-r) and using some `dplyr` idioms:

```
library(dplyr)

Loc1 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B")  
Loc2 <- c("a","a","b","b","a","a","b")  
Dat1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)  
Dat2 <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,2)  
Dat3 <- c(2,2,4,4,6,5,3)  

DF <- data.frame(Loc1, Loc2, Dat1, Dat2, Dat3)  


emitID <- local({
    idCounter <- -1L
    function(){
        idCounter <<- idCounter + 1L 
    }
})

DF %>% group_by(Loc1, Loc2) %>% mutate(Group=emitID())

##   Loc1 Loc2 Dat1 Dat2 Dat3 Group
## 1    A    a    1    1    2     0
## 2    A    a    1    2    2     0
## 3    A    b    1    1    4     1
## 4    A    b    1    2    4     1
## 5    B    a    1    1    6     2
## 6    B    a    1    2    5     2
## 7    B    b    1    2    3     3
```

Comment: I got the following error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "%>%""

Comment: You need to install dplyr