# How to reset non-polluting global counter?

Tags: r

I needed a global counter that didn't pollute the workspace.  I was able to create one as shown below, using another SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25902379/633251).

```
nex <- local(({ # increment a counter and return the ith entry
  i <- 0L
  function(v) {
    if (i == length(v)) i <<- 0L
    i <<- i + 1L
    return(v[i])
  }
}))
```

I can use `nex` in a function as follows and it works correctly; `i` is not in the workspace.

```
magic <- function(num_vec) {
  tmp <- nex(num_vec)
  print(tmp) # output is correct
}
```

Run it:

```
jnk <- magic(1:5) # works as expected, i is not in workspace
```

Now for the question! `i` resides in it's own special environment.  In the larger context I am working in, I need to be able to reset `i` to 1 at certain points. I'm not sure how to reset it, as I can't find where it is stashed. How can I acess `i` to reset it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
environment(nex)$i <- 0
```

Comment: Great!  That seems to work.  Where is this documented?  `environment(nex)` returns a hash, `str(environment(nex))` does too.  There are no arguments to `environment` that seem to apply.  Thanks.

Comment: `environment(nex)` returns the `local` environment of your function, where the `i` counter resides. Try e.g. `ls(environment(nex))`

Comment: ...and, as usual, `environment` is documented in `?environment`.

Comment: I certainly looked in there.  I find all the docs around this topic a bit opaque.